# In islam, if my physical and emotional abusive mother curses me and wishes to ruin my life, will that happen since mothers play a huge role in islam?

Tags: quran, dua

my mother swears she curses me and that my life will be ruined. i have done nothing wrong but to stand up for all the abusive she has done to me.

she also favours my siblings over me and treats me the worst.
she associates everything bad with me